# Big Oh Notation for 2 nested for loop in finding duplicate element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, duplicates, big-o

```
for i=1 to n
 for j=i+1 to n
  if A[i]==B[j] return TRUE
return FALSE
```

Query : in this above nested for loop --> 1st for loop has n iterations
2nd loop has n-1 iterations.

so n(n-1) iterations happens.
But it is actually n(n-1)/2 times. wondering how does it is one more half the times. need help.

Comment: big o doesn't care about constants. and big o only cares about the fastest growing value. n(n-1)/2 == n^2

Comment: @njzk2 yes big oh notation ignores the constants and lower order terms. But my question was --> the iteration is n(n-1) which is supposed to be n^2-n  but the actual one is n(n-1)/2. i am in need of help of explaining the no of iterations in the loop .

Comment: what do you mean by this btw? `1=i=1`.

Comment: @Siva if you already know that, then I'm not sure what you question is?

Comment: Your middle loop runs `n-1` for the first iteration then `n-2` on next, `n-3` after than etc down to `0`. Are you sure the answer is `n(n-1)/2 ` and not `n(n+1)/2` (note the `+`)

Comment: It's not actually `n*(n - 1)` iterations. The number of iterations are `(n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + (n - (n - 1))` which simplifies to `n * (n - 1) / 2`

Comment: @NickParsons that was a typo and it is updated now. Thank you for explaining the middle loop iteration.

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci is right.  To have `n*(n-1)` iterations the inner loop should have had a fixed lower limit `for j = 1 to n - 1`.  But in this case the number of iterations is decreasing this forming an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) of `n - 1` elements from `n - 1` to 1, so its sum is (1 + n - 1)*(n - 1)/2

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci  Thanks for the explanation which simplifies to n(n-1)/2 . Is this is for middle loop alone --> n*n-1)/2  because the first loop we have default n iteration and second loop is the one which is little bit in chaos.

Comment: @Siva think about placing a statement (like a print statement) inside the nested loop, now think of how many times will statement be executed?

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci thank you. printed statement gets executed the number of times the for loop iterations completed.

Comment: @Siva yes, so if you put that in numbers you'll end up with `n * (n - 1) / 2` times the print statement is executed.

Comment: @AlexRudenko thanks for explaining the lower limit in the second for loop is not fixed an we have an A.P of order n-1,n-2,n-3......1.  A.P formula is a+(n-1)d. Where we can get a=n-1 and d=(n-2-(n-1)=-1  and which gives A.P= (n-1)+(1-1)(-1)=n-1 ; this is how i am getting chaos. not sure where i am missing it and where comes divided by 2 :( just curios.

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci  heyyy got it thanks finally cheerszz :) assumed n= 4 and it's like 3+2+1 =  6 times statement getting printed and which gives 4(4-1)/2 = 12/2--> 6 :)  thank you All.

Answer (score 0):

Worst-case time complexity of your nested loops' algorithm is ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)***.

Lower order terms and constant factors are disregarded when the *Asymptotic Analysis* is performed, so it doesn't matter whether you're having `n(n-1)`, `n*(n-1)/2`, `n*(n-5)/6` or etc. important point is that you're having highest order in these expressions *N<sup>2</sup>*, and that's the time complexity.